# How to data bind DataGrid component without scrolling up?

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, datagrid, scrollbar

I have a DataGrid component that I would like to update every 5 seconds. As rows are being added to this DataGrid I noticed that every update causes it to reset the scroll bar position to the top. How can I manage to keep the scroll bar at its previous position?

Comment: Thanks! Your code helped me to sync 3 different data grid scroll bar to same row.
Saved my data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a little extension class to `DataGrid` based on [this article](http://joelhooks.com/2008/02/07/flex-preventing-datagrid-scrolling-when-the-dataprovider-is-updated/). It seems to work great.

```
public final class DataGridEx extends DataGrid
{
    public var maintainScrollAfterDataBind:Boolean = true;

    public function DataGridEx()
    {
        super();
    }       

    override public function set dataProvider(value:Object):void {
        var lastVerticalScrollPosition:int = this.verticalScrollPosition;
        var lastHorizontalScrollPosition:int = this.horizontalScrollPosition;

        super.dataProvider = value;

        if(maintainScrollAfterDataBind) {
            this.verticalScrollPosition = lastVerticalScrollPosition;
            this.horizontalScrollPosition = lastHorizontalScrollPosition;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make a variable to store your last scroll position and use that.

roughly something like:

```
var lastScroll:Number = 0;

private function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void{
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, updateLastScroll);
}

private function updateLastScroll(event:MouseEvent):void{
lastScroll = myDataGrid.verticalScrollPosition
}
private function dataGridHandler(event:Event):void{
myDataGrid.verticalScrollPosition = lastScroll;
}
```

It's not the best code, but it illustrates the point, whenever someone finishes the scroll event, you store last position in a variable and you use that to restore the scroll position right after you've added new data.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code, but it should work:

```
var r:IListItemRenderer;
var len:Number = dataGrid.dataProvider.length;
var i:Number;
//indexToItemRenderer returns null for items that are not visible
for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
  r = dataGrid.indexToItemRenderer(i);
  if(r)
    break;
}
//now i contains the first visible item - store this in a variable
lastPos = i;

//update the dataprovider here.

//now scroll to the position
dataGrid.scrollToIndex(lastPos);
```

Answer (score -1):

These might help:

[Maintain Scroll Position after Asynchronous Postback](http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewfrederick/archive/2008/03/04/maintain-scroll-position-after-asynchronous-postback.aspx)
[Maintaining Scroll Position on Postback](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020135953/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/111506-1.aspx) (Scroll further down to read this)

Comment: (-1) I'm using Flex - not ASP.Net.